# Meteor Mongo find does not work for _id: 0

Tags: mongodb, meteor, find, mongodb-query, minimongo

I have a template named `qa` and inside it I am using a helper named `question`, which will get the `text` field of my document, based on the `_id` property.

```
Template.qa.helpers({
    question: function () {
        return Questions.find({_id: 24}).fetch()[0].text;
    }
});
```

This works fine for all `_id` values unless I use `_id: 0`, then nothing is returned. I run `db.questions.find({_id: 0})` on the minimongo console, and it does return a document.

```
{ "_id" : 0, "author" : 0, "create" : "2014-12-22T13:26:23.038Z", "liked" : [ ], "range" : "", "text" : "I want to get this text", "update" : "2014-12-22T13:26:23.038Z", "version" : 1 }
```

Can I not use `_id: 0` in `collection.find()` for Meteor?

**Clarification: I do not want to return all fields except `_id`, I want to find/select based on the `_id` value. But it does not work if the `_id` is 0.**

Comment: Did you try `var intId = parseInt(0); return Questions.find({_id: intId})` so that you actually pass an integer value instead of a falsy one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to avoid [falsy](http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/) _id values.  Meteor replaces a falsy _id with a random number to prevent it ever going to the database.  The comments on [the code](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/mongo/collection.js#L330) explain it:

```
// protect against dangerous selectors.  falsey and {_id: falsey} are both
// likely programmer error, and not what you want, particularly for destructive
// operations.  JS regexps don't serialize over DDP but can be trivially
// replaced by $regex.
```